# OpenOCD + nRF52810 + ST Link V2 load sample hex

Tags: bluetooth, openocd

I have module nRF52810, which I want to load a sample hex from internet. I wanted to use OpenOCD program to that but I have a few problems

when I use that the command

```
openocd -f interface/stlink.cfg -f target/nrf52.cfg -c "reset_config none; program s112_nrf52_6.1.0_softdevice.hex verify reset exit"
```

I got this output

```
K:\hex_folder\s112_nrf52_6.1.0>openocd -f interface/stlink.cfg -f target/nrf52.cfg -c "reset_config none; program s112_nrf52_6.1.0_softdevice.hex verify reset ex
it"
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0 (2018-07-28) [https://github.com/sysprogs/openocd]
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 950 kHz
none separate
Info : clock speed 950 kHz
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v17 API v2 SWIM v4 VID 0x0483 PID 0x3748
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 3.243886
Info : nrf52.cpu: hardware has 0 breakpoints, 2 watchpoints
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Error: timed out while waiting for target halted
TARGET: nrf52.cpu - Not halted
in procedure 'program'
in procedure 'reset' called at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 491
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'

** Unable to reset target **
shutdown command invoked

Warn : Flash driver of nrf52.flash does not support free_driver_priv()
Warn : Flash driver of nrf52.uicr does not support free_driver_priv()
```

and I don't understand why...
Could you tell your idea, what is reason of "Halted"?

end part of output command in debug mode

```
Debug: 322 2303 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_nrf52.cpu invoke-event examine-start
Debug: 323 2312 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_nrf52.cpu ocd_nrf52.cpu invoke-event examine-start
Debug: 324 2321 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_nrf52.cpu arp_examine allow-defer
Debug: 325 2329 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_nrf52.cpu ocd_nrf52.cpu arp_examine allow-defer
Debug: 326 2337 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_nrf52.cpu invoke-event examine-end
Debug: 327 2344 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_nrf52.cpu ocd_nrf52.cpu invoke-event examine-end
Debug: 328 2353 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_nrf52.cpu invoke-event reset-assert-pre
Debug: 329 2363 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_nrf52.cpu ocd_nrf52.cpu invoke-event reset-assert-pre
Debug: 330 2364 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_transport select
Debug: 331 2374 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_transport ocd_transport select
Debug: 332 2384 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_nrf52.cpu arp_reset assert 1
Debug: 333 2394 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_nrf52.cpu ocd_nrf52.cpu arp_reset assert 1
Debug: 334 2394 target.c:1983 target_free_all_working_areas_restore(): freeing all working areas
Debug: 335 2404 hla_target.c:503 adapter_assert_reset(): adapter_assert_reset
Debug: 336 2404 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_nrf52.cpu invoke-event reset-assert-post
Debug: 337 2414 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_nrf52.cpu ocd_nrf52.cpu invoke-event reset-assert-post
Debug: 338 2424 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_nrf52.cpu invoke-event reset-deassert-pre
Debug: 339 2434 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_nrf52.cpu ocd_nrf52.cpu invoke-event reset-deassert-pre
Debug: 340 2434 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_transport select
Debug: 341 2445 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_transport ocd_transport select
Debug: 342 2445 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_nrf52.cpu arp_reset deassert 1
Debug: 343 2455 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_nrf52.cpu ocd_nrf52.cpu arp_reset deassert 1
Debug: 344 2465 target.c:1983 target_free_all_working_areas_restore(): freeing all working areas
Debug: 345 2465 hla_target.c:566 adapter_deassert_reset(): adapter_deassert_reset
Debug: 346 2475 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_nrf52.cpu invoke-event reset-deassert-post
Debug: 347 2476 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_nrf52.cpu ocd_nrf52.cpu invoke-event reset-deassert-post
Debug: 348 2486 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_transport select
Debug: 349 2496 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_transport ocd_transport select
Debug: 350 2507 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_nrf52.cpu was_examined
Debug: 351 2517 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_nrf52.cpu ocd_nrf52.cpu was_examined
Debug: 352 2517 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_nrf52.cpu arp_waitstate halted 1000
Debug: 353 2527 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_nrf52.cpu ocd_nrf52.cpu arp_waitstate halted 1000
Debug: 354 2538 target.c:2968 target_wait_state(): waiting for target halted...
Debug: 355 3039 log.c:439 keep_alive(): keep_alive() was not invoked in the 1000ms timelimit (1299). This may cause trouble with GDB connections.
Error: 358 3540 target.c:2976 target_wait_state(): timed out while waiting for target halted
Debug: 359 3540 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_nrf52.cpu curstate
Debug: 360 3550 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_nrf52.cpu ocd_nrf52.cpu curstate
User : 361 3560 command.c:544 command_print(): TARGET: nrf52.cpu - Not halted
in procedure 'program'
in procedure 'reset' called at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 491
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'

Debug: 362 3570 command.c:642 run_command(): Command failed with error code -4
Debug: 363 3580 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_echo ** Unable to reset target **
Debug: 364 3590 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - echo ocd_echo ** Unable to reset target **
User : 366 3590 command.c:780 jim_echo(): ** Unable to reset target **
Debug: 367 3600 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_shutdown error
Debug: 368 3610 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - shutdown ocd_shutdown error
User : 370 3610 server.c:703 handle_shutdown_command(): shutdown command invoked
Debug: 371 3620 command.c:642 run_command(): Command failed with error code -4
User : 372 3620 command.c:705 command_run_line():
Debug: 373 3630 target.c:1983 target_free_all_working_areas_restore(): freeing all working areas
Warn : 374 3630 core.c:189 flash_free_all_banks(): Flash driver of nrf52.flash does not support free_driver_priv()
Warn : 375 3640 core.c:189 flash_free_all_banks(): Flash driver of nrf52.uicr does not support free_driver_priv()
Debug: 376 3650 hla_interface.c:117 hl_interface_quit(): hl_interface_quit
```

Can you get me any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: No idea, did you ever figure this out?